# Making rowDrag conditional based on row data with dragging & row grouping

Tags: ag-grid

I am working with the ag-grid rowDrag capabilities and would like to enable and disable rowDrag based on the data in each row.  It looks like rowDrag can contains a condition, but its unclear how to access the fields.

```
<AgGridColumn field="myOffer" rowDrag={fieldMyOffer === 'test' ? rowDrag : undefined} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to dynamically control which rows are draggable by providing a callback function as shown below:

```
const athleteRowDrag = params => params.data.athlete === "Michael Phelps";

<AgGridReact>
    <AgGridColumn field="athlete" rowDrag={athleteRowDrag} />
</AgGridReact>
```

Documentation on [Row Dragging](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/row-dragging/#enabling-row-dragging)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to Shuheb's answer, since I ran into this:

If the cell you are checking is BLANK

```
rowDrag: params => params.data.type === "",
```

will **not** work. You have to do:

```
rowDrag: params => params.data.type.length > 1,
```

Ag-grid seems to insert a space in there somewhere so checking for an empty string or checking that length > 0 doesn't work. I spent several hours trying to get this to work.

Might file a git issue on this one, as my data clearly shows it's an empty string.